# Splitting the letters based on position of letter

Tags: c#

I am trying to spilt a string word into two strings based on the letter position. The two strings are even and odd. I manage to read the string and used a for loop but the conditional operator is not working and give me the error below. What did I do wrong?

Example:  The string word is pole
Even position string - oe
Odd position string  - pl

Error

```
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

```
string word = Console.ReadLine(); 
for(int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
     string even = "";
     string odd = ""; 
           
     ((i % 2 == 0) ? even += word[i]: odd += word[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that familiar with the `?` operator, however, in my research, it appears it wants something like below…

```
((i % 2 == 0) ? ref even : ref odd) += word[i];
```

Unfortunately, even with this change, the `even` and `odd` variables are getting “reset” to empty with each iteration of the `for` loop with…

```
string even = "";
string odd = "";
```

If the goal is to concatenate the values, you do NOT want to create new `even` and `odd` variables with each iteration. So you should move those declarations “outside” the `for` loop. Something like…

```
string word = Console.ReadLine();
string even = "";
string odd = "";
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++) {
  ((i % 2 == 0) ? ref even : ref odd) += word[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the discard operator as the following.

```
string word = Console.ReadLine(); 
string even = "";
string odd = ""; 
for(int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
      
   var _ = ((i % 2 == 0) ? even += word[i]: odd += word[i]);
}
```

Couple of points to note here.

- You need to declare the `odd`,`even` variables outside the loop, otherwise it would be recreated for each iteration of loop
- Remember the string is immutable.You could also consider the StringBuilder class.

Answer (score 1):

You use [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to assign values inside of it. It is not allowed.
The correct for-loop is:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                even += word[i];
            }
            else
            {
                odd += word[i];
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use LINQ to get the expected result:

```
string word = Console.ReadLine(); 
string even = string.Concat(word.Where((c,i) => i % 2 == 0));
string odd = string.Concat(word.Where((c,i) => i % 2 == 1));
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ePWHnp